# Sparse input for LS-SVM

Tags: svm, sparse-matrix, pca

I am trying to use the features from Deep Neural Networks (DNN) to train the Lease Squared SVM. The standard procedure to solve the LS-SVM is to inverse the kernel matrix. However, the kernel matrix from the feature of DNN is not full rank. Does anyone know how to transfer this sparse matrix to a full rank matrix without losing much information? Is PCA a good candidate solution to reduce the input dimension and make it dense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing things. Kernel matrix is a matrix of pairwise dot products, these are **not features**. If you have your feature matrix F, which is sparse and of size N x H, then your kernel matrix (using linear kernel on top of this space) is simply:

```
K = F F'
```

which is N x N, and dense, thus there is no problem with applying any kind of SVM.

Comment: Still when I checked the kernel matrix, it is not full ranked. Therefore, the inverse is not accurate and the performance is poor as well.

Comment: This is why LS-SVM is not inverting kernel matrix, but a sum of kernel matrix and epsilon*I, which efficiently adds L2 regularization. Again - this has nothing to do with sparseness